# How to resolve 'Failed to resolve module specifier "assert". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".'

Tags: javascript, object, import

I am trying to export some of the variables from one js file to another js file but as soon as I am importing the variables in my in-browser javascript, it is showing 'Failed to resolve module specifier "assert". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".'. Any ideas how to solve this?